# Issues with HTTP post when submit spark application to HDInsights

Tags: scala, apache-spark, http-post, azure-hdinsight

I am using the Scala programming language.

The below code works fine when I run it in the Scala worksheet.

I have two questions:

1. When I submit a Spark application (with the same code) to HDInsights, I get this exception:

   > User class threw exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: url-Dev: Name or service not known.

   Why is it not finding url-Dev?
2. How can I pass credentials to this post request?

   ```
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
   import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
   import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

   val url = "http://url-Dev";
   val post = new HttpPost(url)
   post.setEntity(new StringEntity("json"))

   val client = new DefaultHttpClient   
   val response = client.execute(post)    
   val entity = response.getEntity()    
   val content = EntityUtils.toString(entity)
   println(content)
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url-dev is local address in your network. HDInsight cluster runs in the Virtual Network in Azure. It wouldn't have connectivity to your local network from there. You need to expose url-dev to Internet in secure manner so it can be reached to from Azure and then use that public end-point and auth mechanism. You can also do more advanced option of peering of local network with Azure VNet.